# 2010 List Grouping not staying expanded after edit

Tags: 2010, grouping

I have a list that I am grouping.  In the previous version, when an edit was made, the group I was working in would stay expanded so I could just move onto the next item.  In the 2010 version, it collapses each time an edit is made. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce. Do you have any customizations?

Comment: No.  It's a normal list with 2 groupings.  I expand both to reveal data and then update an item.  I click save and it goes back to the grouped view.  I then have to re-expand both groups to get to the data. - Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: What group settings you have "Collapsed or Expanded"?

Comment: I use collapsed.

Comment: Try to create a new view and see if you can reproduce this in the new view

Comment: Now it's working properly.. strange.  Thanks for the help.  Will re-create views.

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Comment: Make sure that the grouping properties of the one that will not stay expanded have good values

Answer (score 1):

The view you are currently using is corrupted. This might have happened because of editing in designer or something else.

Create a new view based on the existing view and delete the existing view.